# Does $\partial^\mu X^\nu = \partial_\mu X_\nu$ (Neumann Boundary Conditions)?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, string-theory, tensor-calculus, noethers-theorem, poincare-symmetry

**Problem**

**I am trying to prove that the Neumann boundary condition , $\partial_\sigma X_\mu=0$ , implies that no momentum flows out of the end of an open string.**

I'm told that the associated conserved charge (of the Noether currents associated to the Poincaré's symmetries) is equivalent to the spacetime momentum for the string ($p^\mu$), as shown in $(1)$:

$$P^\mu = \int ^\pi_0d\sigma(P^\mu)^0= \int^\pi _0 d\sigma T \partial^ 0X^\mu= \pi Tl^2p^\mu=p^\mu \tag{1}$$

**My take on it**

To prove the first statement I thought that I could apply the boundary condition in $(1)$ above, in the form of  $\partial^\sigma X^\mu=0$ and that so $\partial^0 X^\mu=0$, making $P^\mu =0$.

But to do that, I would have to consider $\partial_\sigma X_\mu=\partial^\sigma X^\mu$.

**Is this possible? How can I do this transformation?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Lagrangian symmetries ${\mathcal{P}^{\alpha}_\mu}$ are the conserved world sheet currents, $\partial_{\alpha}{\mathcal{P}^{\alpha}_\mu}=0$.

$$
\partial_{\alpha}{\mathcal{P}^{\alpha}_\mu}=\frac{\partial {\mathcal{P}^{\tau}_\mu}}{\partial\tau}+\frac{\partial {\mathcal{P}^{\sigma}_\mu}}{\partial\sigma}=0
$$

And the conserved charges are the integral of the zeroth components   ${\mathcal{P}^{\tau}_\mu}$  of the currents over space. 
$$p(\tau)=\int_0^\pi {\mathcal{P}^{\sigma}_\mu}(\tau,\sigma)d\sigma$$
$$\frac{d{p_{\mu}(\tau)}}{d\tau}=\int_0^\pi \frac{\partial {\mathcal{P}^{\tau}_\mu}}{\partial\tau}d\sigma= -\int_0^\pi\frac{\partial {\mathcal{P}^{\sigma}_\mu}}{\partial\sigma}d\sigma=-{\mathcal{P}^{\sigma}_\mu}(\pi)+{\mathcal{P}^{\sigma}_\mu}(0)$$

According to the Newmann boundary conditions ${\mathcal{P}^{\sigma}_\mu}$ vanishes at the endpoints. So, $p_\mu(\tau)=const$

Comment: The proof of the current conservation simply comes from Noether's theorem and Euler-Lagrange equations.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, but I have some questions I hope you don't mind me asking.

Shouldn't the sign be different on the first equation as to respect (-,+,+,+) or (+,-,-,-)?
Why doesn't this apply to this case?

Everything else makes perfect sense in my head, thank you so much

Comment: I have just noticed that this doesn't change the second part, my apoligies.

Comment: What transformation are you saying?

Comment: On the first equation, I thought the time component would have a different direction to the space components (-,+,+,+), resulting in :

$$\partial_\alpha P^\alpha _\mu = - \frac{\partial P^\tau_\mu}{\partial_\tau} + \frac{\partial P^\sigma_\mu}{\partial_\sigma} =0$$

Comment: This is Einstein's summation over the dummy indices.

Comment: Makes sense now, sorry for the silly question. Thanks

Comment: I corrected the answer.